# Function overriding in solidity, accessing internal function

Tags: inheritance, overriding, solidity, openzeppelin

I want to override transferOwnership from [Ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) However, the internal function, _transferOwnership, is not being recognized. I either have to have a way to call this or to alter _transferOwnership directly.

```
function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
    _transferOwnership(newOwner);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you're missing is the `override` keyword.

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html#function-overriding

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyContract is Ownable {
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual override onlyOwner {
        // TODO your own implementation
    }
}
```

*Note: You can also remove the `virtual` keyword if you don't want/need this function to be further overwritable (by contracts deriving from the `MyContract`).*